# Is Mathematics or Computer Science more important for a career in cryptography

Tags: education

I'm a Mathematics Major, and I currently enjoy the mathematical aspects of cryptography. I intend to pursue a career in cryptography research.

https://www.csit.gov.sg/join-us/job-opportunities/job-detail/cryptologist

However, although I'm comfortable with the mathematical aspects of it, I lack sufficient training in computer science and computer programming. Therefore, I'm trying to pick up programming and computer science skills at the moment. Are programming skills/computer science important for cryptography? (With respect to the job listed above)

And if so, which computer science topics are most relevant to cryptography? Are topics in data structures necessary for cryptography research? And lastly, how good do my programming skills need to be in order to pursue a career in cryptography? (Such as in the job listed above)

Comment: This is quite a strange position. The main requirement is to *Conduct and lead research in cryptography*. But *Prior knowledge of cryptography is not essential*. How can one conduct and lead research without knowledge in this field?

Comment: Even though they say 'Prior knowledge of cryptography is not essential', but in truth they require it and they will look into your past experience in Cryptography during the hiring process, I guess they mention that simply because they want to attract more candidates to apply for the job.

Comment: Maybe they dont require the candidate to the extent of having prior research experience, but at the very least they expect their prospective candidates to do Cryptography projects before as a pre-requisite, such as doing a final year project in Cryptography.

Comment: @mentallurg A can do mentality, communication skills and positive outlook is a lot more important than domain knowledge.  Anyone can learn bog crypto stuff (just read Quora or here for a few weeks). Leadership and strategic thought is what MINDEF are probably after, which are genetic traits.  Progressives hire staff on the basis of (inter) personality rather than current ability.  That's recognised by the military and the   reason underlying _'Prior knowledge of cryptography is not essential'._

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question can be closed because the answers are opinion based. Nevertheless...

It depends. It does not look like they are going to design essentially new algorithms for encryption, signature, voting, etc. They have focus rather on applied aspects. In particular, they expect you to study and evaluate cryptographic algorithms and protocols of specific hardware and software. To be able to do that you definitely need skills in computer science.

Why are you asking about data structures particularly? It is a small topic compared to the others. Yes you should learn it, not because of this job, but because otherwise you will not be able to program.

To your questions: Yes, programming skills are important for this type of job.

Which topics are relevant? For this job following topics *seem to be* relevant:

- Cryptography (of course)
- Number theory
- Programming
- Software Architecture
- Computer security
- Networking

Comment: What about this job? https://www.glassdoor.sg/job-listing/applied-cryptography-engineer-govtech-JV_IC3235921_KO0,29_KE30,37.htm?jl=3304303152

Comment: I would say, programming is probably among the less required skills in CS for jobs in cryptography. Other things like complexity theory, algorithm theory, etc (well, most of theoretic computer science) are quite important as well. And there are others, where some basics are very useful, e.g. in OS design, parallel computing, server infrastructure, etc.